# "Error: AccountRoutingModule is not an NgModule"

Tags: angular, angular2-cli

Upgrading my `Angular 2.2.3` application from `Angular CLI 2.0.0-beta.21` to `Angular CLI 2.0.0-beta.22-1`, my `ng build` now fails with:

```
Error: AccountRoutingModule is not an NgModule
    at AotPlugin.getNgModuleMetadata (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:332:19)
    at /home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:345:51
    at Array.map (native)
    at AotPlugin.extractLoadChildren (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:343:14)
    at /home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:346:30
    at Array.map (native)
    at AotPlugin.extractLoadChildren (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:343:14)
    at AotPlugin._processNgModule (/home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:272:38)
    at /home/jan/src/fm-repos/fm-ui/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:242:39
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
```

The application built and ran fine with `Angular CLI 2.0.0-beta.21`; however, `Angular CLI 2.0.0-beta.22-1` now uses AoT by default instead of JiT.

Comment: Care to explain the down-vote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `AccountRoutingModule` from:

```
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
```

to:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 2):

A similar error happened to me when I changed this line in the devDependencies section of package.json :

"typescript": "~2.0.0",
to
"typescript": "~2.1.4",

in an attempt to use the latest (at the time) edition of TypeScript.

When I "dialed it back a bit" to this:
"typescript": "~2.0.10",

the error went away.

I hope this helps.