# 'AppModule is not an NgModule' error, despite setting Typescript to version 2.0.10

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I seem to have a very similar problem like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41108456/error-accountroutingmodule-is-not-an-ngmodule) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41420619/error-appmodule-is-not-an-ngmodule), using Angular CLI 1.0.0-beta.24 and Angular 2.4.1.

However, setting my Typescript version to 2.0.10 does not help, still getting 'AppModule is not an NgModule' when running `ng build`.

Here is my package.json, am I using wrong dependencies or versions somewhere?

```
{
 "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "karma": "karma start karma.conf.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.2",
    "less": "~2.7.1",
    "lato-font": "2.0.0",
    "primeui": "^4.1.15",
    "primeng": "1.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.2",
    "systemjs": "0.19.40",
    "zone.js": "0.7.4",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "chart.js": "2.4.0",
    "@types/google.visualization": "0.0.33"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.35",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "es-module-loader": "^1.3.5",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "karma-systemjs": "^0.16.0",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.2",
    "webdriver-manager": "11.1.0",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "protractor": "4.0.14",
    "ts-node": "2.0.0",
    "tslint": "4.2.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not use the latest version of TypeScript?

Comment: It is incompatible with the newest CLI. Please read the links I provided.

Comment: Those are links to other questions where people claimed downgrading TypeScript fixed their issue. It hasn't for you if `tsc -v` returns `2.0.10`

Comment: Thanks for summarizing my problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with the following package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.2",
    "less": "~2.7.1",
    "lato-font": "2.0.0",
    "primeui": "^4.1.15",
    "primeng": "1.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.7.4",
    "font-awesome": "4.7.0",
    "moment": "2.17.1",
    "chart.js": "2.4.0",
    "@types/google.visualization": "0.0.33"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "es-module-loader": "^1.3.5",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "codelyzer": "2.0.0-beta.4",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "karma-requirejs": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.26",
    "requirejs": "^2.3.2",
    "typescript": "2.0.10",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "protractor": "4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Please note the missing '^' in the typescript version...
With the '^' it still downloaded version 2.1.4.